# Ruby each loop separate by commas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying to get this loop to separate the results by a comma:

```
<% @regions.each do |region| %>
  <%= link_to region.name, region_path(region) %>
<% end %>
```

If I do this, it adds a comma after the last result:

```
<% @regions.each do |region| %>
  <%= link_to region.name, region_path(region) %>,&nbsp;
<% end %>
```

There must be an elegant way.

Comment: The elegant way is not to use a comma after a link nor put multiple links on the same line.

Comment: Instead of `link_to region.name, region_path(region)` you can simply write `link_to region.name, region`. Rails is smart enough to figure out the path for an object (if everything is set up correctly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<%= safe_join(@regions.map { |region| link_to(region.name, region_path(region)) }, ', ') %>
```

Comment: That's just the thing I was looking for, although this gives me the ```unexpected keyword_end``` error.

Comment: Sorry, I left a superfluous `end` I have updated an answer. After all, one might prepare and set another instance variable in the view.

Comment: I'm getting this result. I'm fairly new to Ruby. How can I fix this? <a href="/regions/averia">Averia</a>, <a href="/regions/ildoria">Ildoria</a>

Comment: Uhmmm... And what do you expect to get? The above looks pretty fine to me.

Comment: That's what it's rendering in the browser. It's displaying the html without parsing any of it.

Comment: I don't want to sound unappreciative, I'm just trying to understand all of what's happening.

Comment: No, no, don’t hesitate to ask, that’s the main reason of this site existence. I am trying to figure out what’s wrong.

Comment: IIRC you need [`safe_join`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join).